# Mobile Apps Reviews - Need a solution to get reviews of a app

Tags: google-play, app-store, google-play-developer-api, windows-phone-store

Is there any solution available which I can use to get the reviews of the any application hosted over playstore or app store or windows phone store.

Comment: I'd check out https://appfigures.com/ or something like that.

Comment: "App Annie" is a popular one.

Comment: any idea how these sites get the reviews data ?

Answer (score 0):

Telescope (https://telescope-app.com/) is a good site that aggregates both iOS and Android apps. It also supports Slack and email notifications.

Comment: I would rather go for free tool instead of paid. Let me know if there is any free tool available.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing is this tools based on web crawling ??